# What happens to a github student account's repositories at the end of 2 years?

Tags: github

I just got upgraded to a free github micro plan using my university email address. I'm planning to use the private repositories for some class projects this semester, but I'm wondering what will happen to those repositories at the end of 2 years when my free student upgrade expires. I'm assuming it's the same thing that happens when you downgrade from a micro to a free account.

Will my repositories disappear, become public, or just become read-only? I've searched around a bit and haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: There was never a case where GitHub would remove the repositories.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

(Disclosure: I work at GitHub)

So long as you're still a student, you're eligible for the academic discount. Once your coupon expires, you can [re-apply](https://education.github.com/discount) for the student discount.

When you re-apply, be sure you've [added your school-issued email address](https://github.com/settings/emails) to your account, that will expedite the approval process.

You will receive a notification email before your discount expires. When the discount does expire, your account will be [locked](https://help.github.com/articles/unlocking-a-locked-account) which means that you won't be able to access your private repositories. Your private repositories will not be deleted and they will not be made public.

Of course, if you ever have any troubles, you can always email support@github.com.

Comment: Is it just that any private repos become inaccessible? If I make the few I have private public will I retain the full source, history and access I've always had as a free account? Or am I required to pay or loose the whole account?

Comment: Ok, so the user can manually make the repo's public **prior to or after** the automatic downgrade if they do not desire to pay to access their code again.

Comment: Does locked mean I can still export / save / clone but it is just read only. Or are they held hostage?

Comment: @FullDecent: No, you can't clone or access the code via the website for that repo. I left one private test repo up and just tried it. Make sure to bare clone your secret repos beforehand. You can however access the *settings* page of the repo, that means you can e.g. delete it, transfer it to another account or make it public etc.

Comment: `When the discount does expire, your account will be locked` seems not working all the time, my discount is expired but my account is not locked

Comment: GitHub [made private repositories free](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-01-07-pricing-changes) for everyone, so accounts don't get locked anymore.

Answer (score 10):

After the two years, you will have to start paying for private repositories ($7/month) otherwise your repositories will be removed after a retention period.

They will give you 30 days to pay or they will remove the repositories.

Comment: So your answer to the question is "the repositories will disappear".

Comment: I agree, it's not that big of a financial burden—but it's also not worth $7/month to me when I could simply run it on my own server or move to bitbucket instead. (Netflix only costs me a little more than that and I use it way more often!) Anyway, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This answer is wrong given the above Github employee's answer. This answer should be downvoted to show that.

Comment: @Patrick my answer was correct at the time. The GitHub employee answered over a year later after they updated the policy. I still have the email showing what I said.

Comment: If Github told you they were deleting repos after 30 days in an email, that's kind of a big deal. You should definitely include that in your answer--especially because referenceable sources are looked favorably upon in answers.

Comment: What's the point now? The answer I give was back on Sep 11, 2012.  It's been about 6 years ago.

Comment: I'm not sure why people at still looking to this question and voting up and down on it. Things have changed over the years. GitHub now has free private repos.

Answer (score 9):

The timeline of your expiring Educational account is something like this:

- you will get an email/notification in Github announcing you that your education coupon will expire, and ask you to either:

  - make all your private repos public and downgrade to a free account,
  - add a payment method and they will start charging you after the coupon expires, or
  - renew your educational coupon.
- the time comes, and, if you didn't do any of these, they will *lock you out* of your private repos.

**What does this lock means?**

- you cannot access your repo in any way, ie. you cannot even see your files in github, or clone it.

**What can you do to access them?**

- go to each one of your private repos, in settings, and make them public. This will give you access to them, so you can clone or download a copy quickly and then delete them.
- pay for a premium account.
- renew your educational coupon (or any coupon for free premium account).

I had this problem today when I wanted to access one of my private repos.

My free educational plan expired in August. I got a big red notification bar in Github telling me to pay for a Micro plan or to downgrade.
I didn't need my private repos, so I ignored it, until today.

Personally, I find this policy weird, as no other service does this. How will it be if you stopped paying for extra storage on Google Drive, and the next day you find that half your files were hidden until you pay up.

Answer (score 9):

### Updated 2020 answer

I had my student account that expired recently and was asked to either provide billing details to continue on **pro** subscription which now costs USD $4/mo (vs $7/mo previously) or downgrade to a free account.

Downgrading to the free account would still let me keep and access all my private repos (with less number of collaborators allowed I think) while losing access to GitHub Pages and GitHub Wikis within those private repos - so not too bad overall. [This is the message that I received while downgrading my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMsTJ.jpg)

Recent changes to their pricing, features and billing structure by Microsoft resulted in the following features included as part of the free subscription:

> GitHub Free for user accounts
>
> With GitHub Free for user accounts, you can work with unlimited
> collaborators on unlimited public repositories with a full feature
> set, and on unlimited private repositories with a limited feature set.
>
> With GitHub Free, your user account includes:
>
> - GitHub Community Support
> - GitHub Dependabot alerts
> - Two-factor authentication enforcement
> - 2,000 GitHub Actions minutes
> - 500MB GitHub Packages storage

And the pro account includes the following features:

> GitHub Pro
>
> In addition to the features available with GitHub Free for user
> accounts, GitHub Pro includes:
>
> - GitHub Support via email
> - 3,000 GitHub Actions minutes
> - 2GB GitHub Packages storage
> - Advanced tools and insights in private repositories:
>
>   - Required pull request reviewers
>   - Multiple pull request reviewers
>   - Auto-linked references
>   - GitHub Pages
>   - Wikis
>   - Protected branches
>   - Code owners
>   - Repository insights graphs: Pulse, contributors, traffic, commits, code frequency, network, and forks

**Source:** https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/githubs-products#github-pro