# AnroidManifest.xml is suddenly empty and in my directory the characters are in Chinese.

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

Last Night I was working on my application for android (which is currently in the beta test stage on the google play store) and today when I opened up Eclipse I found my Entire workspace missing. After looking on Here for a fix (which involved importing each workspace file into eclipse). I opened up my manifest to find everything gone it is Completely empty. I have put a serious amount of hours into this project I'm scared that I lost this project. 
Would it be possible to retrieve the manifest from an .apk file thats saved not only on the play store but on my pc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4191807/804773 -- Try this. Also BACKUPS

Comment: @TheCapn - I'd recommend using a [_version control system_](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) rather than just making backup copies.

Comment: You can use apktool to extract the manifest back.

Answer (score 3):

If you open up the apk as a zip file, you can get the manifest back.  Unfortunately it will be compiled into 16 bit unicode, but you can convert it to ascii easily enough.

Here's the real question-  why aren't you using source control?  Even for a home project you ought to.  There's free hosts like github if your code is open source, or even free hosts for private repos like assembla for small teams.

Comment: Seriously! Use source control! (a.k.a. revision control or version control) I personally think it's *really stupid* that version control isn't included in the first year of all CompSci / Software Engineering curriculums... You should always have an incremental history of your code just in case you need to roll something back.

Comment: **Pro-tip:** If you are in any educational institute or have an email address linked to one you can request a Scholar account from Github which has a limited number of private repos available too (3-6, can't remember exactly) [Link here](https://education.github.com/)

Comment: @indivisible - You can also get a [free educational account from bitbucket](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/08/20/bitbucket-academic/), which is much less restrictive. I have one of each—but I think my [two year limit on the Github student account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361700/what-happens-to-a-github-student-accounts-repositories-at-the-end-of-2-years) is coming up soon...

Comment: I have Never Heard of Source Control but I saved every version of my .apk on my Computer.

Comment: @DaoWen, Actually, my current account is 2 years old this Aug. Not sure exactly when I requested it be a Student account but I haven't gotten any notifications about the period ending yet.

Comment: How do I translate my manifest back to the original language.

Comment: @Jbarfield101, That is why you should realy use version control. It keeps all the history of every file in its original source and not just the minified, compiled version you currently only have backups of. [Here's a nice, easy introduction to using Git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/). I really can't recommend to you enough that you take the time to learn at least one of the major SourceControl systems such as Git, SVN or Mercurial.